# How can i compare the data from a sheet to another?

Tags: vba, excel

As I have some columns with data in sheet 1 & the same column with approx. same data except some in sheet2  .So I want to compare the data from sheet1 to sheet2 & it should show something what will be easy that data is "Differ" on those cells from sheet1 to sheet2 .

By anyway I want to know where the data are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your first sheet is Sheet1 and the 2nd is Sheet2,
Go to the cell a1 on Sheet2 and on home ribbon select conditional formatting -> highlight cells rules -> equal to -> and on the open window, enter the formula:

```
='Sheet1'!A1
```

press apply.

Now use the format painter brush when you are on the same cell on select all the range you have.

you can choose the color you wish to distinguish between the equal cells with non equal cells on the  'with' on the opened window

Comment: Awesome it is. Actually I did this by using VBA. but the problem was there I have to count the row & column. otherwise I have to make littlebit complex code.
but now it's awesome way to find the differ value. :-)